# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova Android build does not generate all icon sizes

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am building a cross-platform Cordova app with Visual Studio 2017. When building my .apk file, Visual Studio only generates icon assets for the device I have plugged in, not all the sizes that need to be supported in a Play Store release.

Relevant line in my config.xml that defines my icon:

`<icon src="res/icons/icon_psi_color_edges.png" />`

In my .apk file, under `assets/`, VS only creates a `drawable-mdpi-v4` folder, corresponding to the Nexus 4 device I am using as the deployment target.

I would like to have Visual Studio generate all the icon sizes. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Cordova icon generator" (there are quite a few if you search in Google).

We use http://phonegap.appiq.software/ as it not only generates the icons & screens, it also generates the correct xml that you just copy & paste into your config.xml file (replacing the default icon & screen code).